# DKW-style $\ell_{\infty}$ bounds for sum of i.i.d. random functions: $\to [0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, inequality

Let $\mathbf{G}$ be the set of (edit: *convex*) functions $g: X \to [0,1]$, where $X$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ or something like that.

Suppose I have a distribution $D$ on $\mathbf{G}$. Let $\bar{g}: X \to [0,1]$ be the pointwise average
 $$ \bar{g}(x) = \mathbb{E}_{g \sim D} g(x)  . $$

When I draw $n$ functions $g_1,\dots,g_n$ from $D$ i.i.d., let $\hat{g}_n$ be a random variable equalling the empirical pointwise average,
 $$ \hat{g}_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n g_j(x) . $$

Recall that $\| f \|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)|$. I'd ideally like a bound of this sort

$$ \Pr\left[ \| \hat{g}_n - \bar{g} \|_{\infty} > \epsilon \right] ~~ \leq ~~ ??? $$

**Are there known inequalities of this form?** I'd naively hope for something like $O(e^{-n\epsilon^2})$. If it's not true, it'd be great to know conditions that make it true (all functions are continuous, Lipschitz, ...?).

(Edit: (1) I should mention the related [DKW inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality) that inspires this goal. (2) Changed the condition on functions to be *convex*, due to ClementC.'s counterexample below.)

Comment: How do you draw these functions (what is the distribution)?

Comment: @ClementC., I'm happy to start by assuming it's some distribution on a finite set of functions, in general some "nice enough" distribution that it has an expectation as defined above, and any other assumptions needed. I'm not totally clear what you mean by the question though... (also I'm not worried about computation or actually representing the functions or anything like that.)

Comment: I do think you'll need more assumptions indeed (a very weak "bad example" follows, with a lot of restictions on the range of $\epsilon$). Take the distribution $D$ supported on all functions of the form $g_y\colon x\in[0,1]\mapsto \mathbb{1}_{\{y\}}(x)$, which are $0$ everywhere but on one point, defined as follows: draw $y\in[0,1]$ uniformly at random, and output $g_y$. It seems that the pointwise average is $\bar{g}=0$ (zero function), and for $\epsilon < 1/n$ the probability is $1$.

Comment: @ClementC. thanks, the example makes sense! (and could/should be an answer?) I'm hoping it's true for convex $g$, but I didn't see the sort of example you give so I asked the general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked and answered on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171527/concentration-inequalities-in-ell-infty-for-sums-of-iid-random-nice-fu

The keyword for this type of problem is "empirical process", and references exist.

Answer (score 1):

A small change **("against" continuous function -- *not* convex)**:

Fix any $n>1$, and consider the distribution $D_n$ supported on all piecewise-affine functions of the form $g_y\colon x\in [0,1]\mapsto g_y(x)$, where
$$
g_y(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }x=y\\
0 & \text{if }\lvert x-y \rvert \geq \frac{1}{2n^2}\\
\text{affine otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
$D_n$ is defined by drawing $y\in [0,1]$ uniformly at random, and outputting the continuous function $g_y$. Then
$\bar{g}(x)\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\mathbb{E}_{y\sim \mathcal{U}_{[0,1]}}[ g_y(x)] \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ (as there are at most a set of measure $1/n^2$ of functions $g_y$ which are non-zero on $x$), but for any outcome of the $n$ draws $y_1,\dots,y_n$ (taking for example $x=y_1$, which implies $\hat{g}_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n g_{y_j}(x) \geq \frac{1}{n}$) you have
$$
\lVert\hat{g}_n - \bar{g} \rVert_\infty \geq \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2} \geq \frac{1}{2n}
$$ 
with probability $1$. So for $\epsilon < \frac{1}{2n}$, there cannot be any non-trivial bound of the sort you seek.

Comment: Thanks again for the help! But am I being dense, or are the $g_y$ not convex? $g_{0.5}(0) = g_{0.5}(1) = 0$, but $g_{0.5}(0.5) = 1$?

Comment: (Maybe these are continuous but not convex?)

Comment: Yes, my apologies -- they are only continuous (or piecewise convex, not actually convex).